# Mermaid Flowchart doesn't fit within demo

Tags: markdown, flowchart, mermaid

I'm just starting with mermaid and created the following chart https://mermaidjs.github.io/mermaid-live-editor/#/view/Z3JhcGggVEQKSSgoSSkpLS0-QTJ7QTJ9CkEyIC0tPiBFKEUpCkEyIC0tPiBBKEEpClRbVF0gLS0-IENbQ10KVCAtLT4gTVtNXQpUIC0tPiBFKEUpClQgLS0-IEQoRCkKVCAtLT4gQQpKKEopIC0tPiBDCkogLS0-IE0KSiAtLT4gQQpKIC0tPiBFClIoUikgLS0-IE0KUiAtLT4gUChQKQpBIC0tPiBJCkEgLS0-IEoKQSAtLT4gUjJbUjJdCkEgLS0-IEMKQSAtLT5NCkUgLS0-IEQKRCAtLT4gQwpSMiAtLT4gUjI

[image: The chart]

The code for it is

```
graph TD
I((I))-->A2{A2}
A2 --> E(E)
A2 --> A(A)
T[T] --> C[C]
T --> M[M]
T --> E(E)
T --> D(D)
T --> A
J(J) --> C
J --> M
J --> A
J --> E
R(R) --> M
R --> P(P)
A --> I
A --> J
A --> R2[R2]
A --> C
A --> M
E --> D
D --> C
R2 --> R2
```

I'm trying to figure out if I am doing something wrong or if Mermaid cannot handle charts of this complexity. This is a simplified network diagram which in the long run needs to be more complex. If I change it to point R2 at R it works which makes me think I am not doing something wrong though it may be something I am missing that allows for this.

Answer (score 2):

To improve it, you could break this diagram into sub-graphs.

[image: Graph example here]